# Infinispan cache preserving insertion order

Tags: insertion, infinispan

I'm using Infinispan 5.0.1 for my caching needs.

The problem I'm having is that I need to get data back from the cache in the same order it was put in the cache.
For example:

```
Cache<String, String> myCache = defaultCacheManager.getCache("myCache");
myCache.put("1", "ONE");
myCache.put("2", "TWO");
myCache.put("3", "THREE");
myCache.keySet();
Set<String> keySet = myCache.keySet();
for (String key : keySet) {
    System.out.println(myCache.get(key));
}
```

This should print out:
ONE
TWO
THREE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being I solved this by using [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](http://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/)
and it works good.
Still, if someone knows the answer to the original question of "How to do it in Infinispan" I'd appreciate the anwser.

Answer (score -2):

Why should it print out ONE TWO THREE?  keySet() returns a Set, which is an un-ordered collection.  Please see the Javadocs for Set, to understand its contract.

Comment: Now here you are wrong. LinkedHashMap says in JavaDoc: "This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order)". And if you don't believe me try this snippet:
LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("1", "ONE");
map.put("2", "TWO");
map.put("3", "THREE");
Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
for (String key : keySet) {
    System.out.println(key + " = " + map.get(key));
}